# Find $P(Y(x) > E[Y(x)])$

Tags: probability

Let $X_1, X_2, \ldots$ be i.i.d random variable with common distribution function $F(x)$ satisfying $F(x)<1$ for all $x$. for a given constant $x$ define $Y(x) = \min \{i\mid X_i > x \}$. Find $P(Y(x) > E[Y(x)])$. What is the limit of this probability as $x \rightarrow \infty$?

It seems to me that the probability is $1-F(\frac{1}{1-F(x)})$ and in the limit the probability is 1. Can someone confirm this or give a correct solution?

Comment: When you say $E[Y(X)]$ does $X$ represent yet another i.i.d. random variable with the same cumulative distribution function $F(x)$?

Comment: @Henry Sorry, that $X$ should be lowercase. I have changed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $m(x)=E(Y(x))$. For every positive integer $n$, $P(Y(x)\geqslant n)=F(x)^{n-1}$, hence $$m(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(Y(x)\geqslant n)=\frac1{1-F(x)}.$$
For every positive real number $t$, $P(Y(x)\geqslant t)=P(Y(x)\geqslant \lceil t\rceil)$ hence 
$$P(Y(x)\geqslant E(Y(x)))=\left(1-\frac1{m(x)}\right)^{\lceil m(x)\rceil-1}.$$
When $x\to\infty$, $m(x)\to+\infty$ hence $$P(Y(x)\geqslant E(Y(x)))\to\frac1{\mathrm e}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Another observation is that $Y(x)$ has Geometric distribution with parameter $p=1-F(x)$ and therefore its mean value is $\frac 1{1-F(x)}$. The question becomes equivalent to finding the following limit:
$$
\Pr(Y\geq \frac 1p)=(1-p)^{[\frac 1{p}]}
$$
when $p\to 0$ which is equal to $\frac 1e$.

Comment: Am I horribly biased or is this repeating the already posted answer?

Comment: I thought the geometric distribution intuition was worth to be mentioned. Makes things more straightforward.